# Referencing DLL's between solutions

Tags: dll, .net-core

I've found an interesting issue with using DLL's in .NET Core (.NET Framework works fine). MVCE as follows:

Create an F# (language is irrelevant) .NET Core class library with the following single file (specific code irrelevant as well):

```
namespace FSharpClassLibrary

module Say =
    let hello name =
        printfn "Hello %s" name
```

Create a C# .NET Core class library *in a separate solution* (very important--it completely works if they are all in the same solution) with the following code:

```
namespace CSharpClassLibrary
{
    public class HelloClass
    {
        public void Hello(string name)
        {
            FSharpClassLibrary.Say.hello(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, add a folder `dlls`, copy/paste `FSharpClassLibrary.dll` into it, and add it as a reference to the project (otherwise, the file above won't compile). It's actually not important to move the `.dll` into the project, but since I'm distributing this second project independently of the first, I need to guarantee the DLL is available.

Finally, add a console app to the same solution as `CSharpClassLibrary` with the following file:

```
using System;
using CSharpClassLibrary;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Main1
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            new HelloClass().Hello("test");

#if DEBUG
            Console.Write("Press any key");
            Console.ReadKey();
#endif
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, go into NuGet and add `FSharp.Core` version 4.3.4 to both C# projects (just to make sure everything has access to the F# language stuff; not necessary if you create the first class library with C#). Also, I am using VS 15.6; this may or may not be relevant as well.

Set the console app as the startup project and run it. You will get the following error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FSharpClassLibrary, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   File name: 'FSharpClassLibrary, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>      at ClassLibrary1.Facade.Hello1.Hello(String name)
>      at ConsoleApp1.Main1.Main() in C:\Users\***\source\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\Main.cs:line 11

The most curious part about this is that if I bypass the `CSharpClassLibrary` library and host `FSharpClassLibrary.dll` and `HelloClass.cs` in the `ConsoleApp1` project, everything works as expected. The same issue happens if I use two C# DLL's, I used F# because that's what I was working with already.

---

What I already tried:

1. Cleaning and rebuilding all projects, making sure each project was referencing the latest build.
2. Referencing the child (`FSharpClassLibrary.dll`) from `ConsoleApp1` as well as `CSharpClassLibrary.dll`.
3. Using the .dll from the `obj` folder instead of the `bin` folder (shouldn't matter as far as I'm aware).
4. Verify that `FSharpClassLibrary.dll` exists in `ConsoleApp1`'s `bin` folder.
5. Double-check that all projects compile to .NET Core, no .NET Standard projects.

Comment: I'm surprised that this works in a single solution. So far as I was aware, references were not treated as transitive (so A referencing B referencing C didn't result in A's bin containing C unless A also directly referenced C). The number of situations where pure transitivity occurs with no leakage are relatively small so it's not often observed. But do you have a *question* here? The solution is obvious - add the missing reference. And .NET assemblies aren't (generally) placed in the registry at all.

Comment: References are transitive in projects using the `Microsoft.NET.Sdk` SDK, did you try building the project from the command line (i.e. `dotnet build`) and then run it (i.e. `dotnet run`)?

Comment: No, I've been using VS. I'll try the commandline next.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for the tip about the registry; I removed that. About referencing the missing reference, I tried that already, and it didn't work. Also, I was a little surprised to see all three .dll's in the executable's `bin` folder given the error, but it does exist.